# iFrameResize is not defined - loaded via CDN & in JS File

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, iframe-resizer

I am trying to make use of [iFrame Resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to resize an iFrame on the same domain based on it's content (which can change).

Live Example: https://bronzecc.co.uk/sunday-2nd-xi/

I am getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined` error but I have checked the iFrames and they all load the correct JS via CDN and I also load the correct JS on that page itself.

For initialising the resizer I am using

```js
var iframes = iFrameResize({log: true}, 'iframe');
```

MCE: https://gist.github.com/shivampaw/7b1dba5326706673a782d115358eca2a

`window.html`

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Window</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html" style="width: 100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.1.1/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        iframes = iFrameResize({}, 'iframe');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`iframe.html`

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>102166</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Match Time</th>
                    <th>Match Type</th>
                    <th>Home Team</th>
                    <th>Away Team</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details_3722786">
                            <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                            <td>28/07/2019 14:00</td>
                            <td>League</td>
                            <td>Bronze CC</td>
                            <td>Wall CC</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="collapse" id="details_3722786">
                            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                                <p>
                                    Ground: The Anson Ground B43 7BA<br />
                                    Start Time: 14:00                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details_3722741">
                            <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                            <td>04/08/2019 14:00</td>
                            <td>League</td>
                            <td>Burntwood St Matthew's CC</td>
                            <td>Bronze CC</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="collapse" id="details_3722741">
                            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                                <p>
                                    Ground: The Riddings<br />
                                    Start Time: 14:00                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details_3722745">
                            <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                            <td>11/08/2019 14:00</td>
                            <td>League</td>
                            <td>Four Oaks Saints CC</td>
                            <td>Bronze CC</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="collapse" id="details_3722745">
                            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                                <p>
                                    Ground: Coalville, Clarence Road, Four Oaks, Sutton Coldfield<br />
                                    Start Time: 14:00                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details_3722710">
                            <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                            <td>18/08/2019 14:00</td>
                            <td>League</td>
                            <td>Bronze CC</td>
                            <td>Wall CC</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="collapse" id="details_3722710">
                            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                                <p>
                                    Ground: The Anson Ground B43 7BA<br />
                                    Start Time: 14:00                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.1.1/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can't figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.  Otherwise it may be impossible to tell *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: MCVE: https://gist.github.com/shivampaw/7b1dba5326706673a782d115358eca2a @ochi

Comment: A good practice is to include the [mcve] code with the question itself. This is because if the link goes dead, the question becomes incomplete and, thus, useless to future community users.  Please edit your question and include it here.

Comment: @ochi all done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation you provided on the first link, it shows [this section on usage](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#usage):

It looks like you have switched the file includes.  The page holding the `iFrame` (i.e. `window.html`)should contain the script `iframeResizer.min.js`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.1.1/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
```

The other page which is the content of the `iFrame` (i.e. `iframe.html`)should contain the other script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.1.1/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

Switch them around and see if it works.

Comment: The scripts the wrong way around was the issue! Thank you for your help!